# How to pickup up a record based on second column is null

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hi I have following table:

Lets say Todays Date is 01-Sep-2016

```
ID  Change_Dt   Cancel_Dt
1   1/1/2015    NULL    
2   1/1/2015    1/1/2015    
3   1/1/2015    2/1/2015
3   3/1/2015    NULL    
4   1/1/2015    12/1/2015
4   1/1/2016    9/1/2016
4   10/1/2016   NULL    
5   10/1/2016   NULL    
6   9/1/2016    9/1/2016    
7   1/1/2015    NULL
7   1/1/2016    9/1/2016
```

Requirement: If across all records if there is atleast one record for an ID where Change_Dt <= Today's date and Cancel_Dt is Null 
then Y
else N

Required Results:

```
ID   Results  Change_Dt Cancel_Dt

1   Y         1/1/2015  NULL
2   N         1/1/2015  1/1/2015
3   Y         3/1/2015  NULL
4   N         10/1/2016 NULL
5   N         10/1/2016 NULL
6   N         9/1/2016  9/1/2016
7   Y         1/1/2015  NULL
```

Any help on this will be great.

My code that I tried:

```
select m.ID, 
Case when(m.Cancel_Dt is null and m.Create_Dt < = '01-SEP-2016')
    then 'Y'
    else 'N'
end Indicators

from mytable m
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: But my code gives me results for my each record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CASE you wrote with a small change. Utilizing the `MAX` over the `CASE`, within yet another `CASE` will allow you to pick the correct value.

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE WHEN 
        MAX(case when(m.Cancel_Dt is null and m.Create_Dt < = '01-SEP-2016')
            then 1
            else 0
        end) = 1 THEN 'Y' 
    ELSE 'N'
    END Indicators 
FROM my_records
GROUP BY ID
```

Note that you don't technically need to use `1` and `0` since `Y` > `N` however this make the query clearer (at least to me).

To get all the columns I'd split the query, and use a `UNION` to get each part:

```
SELECT m.id, 
  'Y' as results, 
  MAX(change_dt) as change_dt, 
  NUll as cancel_dt
FROM my_records m
WHERE m.Cancel_Dt is null
AND m.change_dt <= '2016-09-01'
GROUP BY id

UNION ALL

SELECT m.id, 
  'N',
  MAX(change_dt) as change_dt,
  MAX(cancel_dt) as cancel_dt
FROM my_records m
WHERE (m.Cancel_Dt is not null
OR m.change_dt > '2016-09-01')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
  FROM my_records m2
  WHERE m2.Cancel_Dt is null
  AND m2.change_dt <= '2016-09-01'
  AND m2.id = m.id)
GROUP BY id  
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: I want to pull up related change_date and Cancel_date as well.

Comment: @Qasim0787 see alternate query